# Comparing numbers using a modular hash function?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hash, hashmap

I want to compare b base-b numbers of b digits each to determine which ones are the same, using a hash table. If I use a modular hash function, should I use h(a) = a mod (b) or h(a) = a mod (b-1)? I am not sure how to determine if these are suitable or not.

Comment: **mod b**. Suppose b = 5, if you have 5 numbers, 0 would be equal to 4 if your mod was b-1, what is not true in base 5

Answer (score 0):

So you have `b` numbers in the range `0` ... `b^b - 1` (e.g. `10` numbers in the range `0` ... `9999999999`).

If you want to *guarantee* that the hash function is collision-free, you cannot use `mod`. If you use e.g. `a mod 10`, then `31` and `56465421` both get a hash of 1 and collide, and this happens for every mod below `10000000000`.

So you can only reduce the probability of hash collisions. And the smallest mod value with a chance to avoid collisions is `b` (but most probably, you'll run into collisions then). Without doing proper probability computations, I'd go for something like `mod b*b`, effectively taking the two trailing digits.